# How to add custom hues using seaborn for multiple pointplots?

Tags: seaborn

```
test_results = pd.DataFrame({'Month Number': {0: 11, 1: 2},
 'LSOA code': {0: 60, 1: 67},
 'Actual Frequency': {0: 13, 1: 1},
 'Linear Regression': {0: 3.326444, 1: 3.742185},
 'Ridge Regression': {0: 3.326444, 1: 3.742185}})
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 8))
sns.pointplot(x='Month Number', y='Actual Frequency', ci=False, color='Red', data=test_results)
sns.pointplot(x='Month Number', y='Linear Regression', ci=False, color='Black', data=test_results)
sns.pointplot(x='Month Number', y='Ridge Regression', ci=False, color='Green', data=test_results)
```

I want to diplay a point plots for actual frequency, linear and ridge regression with different colors and add hue to distinguish them.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Please elaborate. I'm guessing you want to be able to do this dynamically in one plot and pass a `hue` parameter? If you want to do that, then you need to manipulate your data first. In future, please format your code as I have done and include your data as text with `test_results.to_dict()` and then put that inside of `pd.DataFrame()`.

Comment: Also, if I have answered your question, the please click the checkmark next to my solution. Please see the following link if you need more information on how to do that: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `melt` your dataframe. Then for your `pointplot`, you only need to specify `hue` rather than creating three separate pointplots:

```
In[1]:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
test_results = pd.DataFrame({'Month Number': {0: 11, 1: 2},
 'LSOA code': {0: 60, 1: 67},
 'Actual Frequency': {0: 13, 1: 1},
 'Linear Regression': {0: 3.326444, 1: 3.742185},
 'Ridge Regression': {0: 3.326444, 1: 3.742185}})
test_results

Out[1]:
   Month Number  LSOA code  Actual Frequency  Linear Regression  Ridge Regression 
0            11         60                13           3.326444          3.326444 
1             2         67                 1           3.742185          3.742185

In[2]:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 8))
test_results = test_results.melt(id_vars='Month Number', value_vars=df.columns[-3:])
test_results

Out[2]: 
   Month Number           variable      value
0            11   Actual Frequency  13.000000
1             2   Actual Frequency   1.000000
2            11  Linear Regression   3.326444
3             2  Linear Regression   3.742185
4            11   Ridge Regression   3.326444
5             2   Ridge Regression   3.742185

In[3]:
sns.pointplot(x='Month Number', y='value', hue='variable', ci=False, color='Red', data=test_results)
```

[image]